# dict.pop or dict.get and evaluation

Tags: python, short-circuiting

Consider the following code:

```
>>> def default_answer():
...     print "Default was required!"
...     return 100
... 
>>> g = { 'name': 'Jordan', 'age': 35 }
>>> result = g.get('age', default_answer())
Default was required!
>>> result = g.pop('age', default_answer())
Default was required!
```

Notice that whether `g` contains the expected key or not, default_answer is called. This makes sense programmatically but if `default_answer` was computationally expensive this would be a hassle (to run a lot of code to create a value that was going to be thrown away).

The only way I can think of writing this without always calling `default_answer` is:

```
result = g.pop('age', False) or default_answer()
```

Is this the best way to do it?

(Note that I'm aware that replacing `default_answer` with an object with lazy evaluation would also solve part of this problem, but that's outside the scope of this question).

Comment: Is `try: ... except:` off the table for some reason?

Comment: Why would you use `pop` for this instead of `get`?

Comment: Why aren't you using a defaultdict (http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) ?

Comment: @mgilson in this case I want the value gone from the dictionary after I've retrieved it.

Comment: @mouad assume that I didn't actually create `g` myself and am receiving it as an input...

Comment: @mouad: A `defaultdict` always comes with the danger of hiding "real" `KeyError`s.

Comment: @JordanReiter -- Sorry, I misunderstood.  I thought you were trying to decide between using `get` or `pop`.  You're looking for an idiom that works with either.

Comment: @mgilson in fairness, Sven's answer below would not work with `result = g.get('age')` although it *would* work with `result = g['age']`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is not the best way to do this, since the result of `g.pop()` might be "falsy".  Use `try`/`except` instead:

```
try:
    result = g.pop('age')
except KeyError:
    result = default_answer()
```

This idiom is called [EAFP](http://docs.python.org//glossary.html#term-eafp) and is usually preferred over [LBYL](http://docs.python.org//glossary.html#term-lbyl) for various reasons:

1. It avoids looking up the key twice (which is not an issue with an actual `dict`, but might be suboptimal with other mappings).
2. It avoids a race condition in threaded code.
3. Many people find it easier to read.

Comment: I was going for a one liner but I've always been a big fan of EAFP in Python so I'll probably try this instead.

Answer (score 2):

That is an okay way as long as you know that any boolean-false value (not just False but also empty string, empty list, etc.) should be replaced by your default.  You can always do it explicitly:

```
if 'age' in g:
    result = g['age']
else:
    result = default_answer()
```

(Or an equivalent version with try/except where you read the value first and do the default in an except clause.  Which one is better depends on whether you expect the missing-value case to be common or uncommon.)

Comment: In Python the `try except` is the preferred way. However, one might consider the `if else` here, as it allows to use an oneliner: `result = g['age'] if 'age' in g else default_answer()`.